# How to backup and restore table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup

During my testing, I want to make a copy of a few tables within the same database before running the tests. After tests are complete, I want to restore the original table with the copy.

What is the best way to do this?
I also want to make sure all indexes and constraints are restored.

```
DECLARE @Tablename NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @BuildStr NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500)
SELECT @Tablename = 'my_Users'
SELECT @BuildStr = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16),GETDATE(),120)
SELECT @BuildStr = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@BuildStr,' 
',''),':',''),'-',''),' ','')
SET @SQL = 'select * into '+@Tablename+'_'+@BuildStr+' from '+@Tablename
SELECT @SQL

EXEC (@SQL) -- Execute SQl statement
```

How do I restore if I use the above to make a copy.

SQL2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are MANY methods to do this, but by far, the simplest is to simply take a backup of the database, work with it, then restore from backup when done. ([Instructions here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429%28SQL.90%29.aspx))

Backing up the table is certainly viable, but it's not the easiest method, and once you start working with multiple tables, it gets harder.  So rather than address your *specific* example of restoring a single table, I'm offering *general* advice on better management of test data.

The ***safest*** way of doing this is to NOT restore the original, but rather to not even touch the original.  Take a backup of it, and then restore it to a new test server. ([Instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx))  Best practices dictate that you should never be doing test or development work on a live database anyway.  This is also pretty easy, as well as safe.

Comment: A backup cannot restore a single table.  Version control stores the definition of a table and not its contents.  -1

Comment: @Andomar, you're right, of course.  I deleted the version control portion, and edited to make my meaning more clear.  I agree with your -1 because I didn't answer his specific question, but I'm leaving it here because I think it's still better general advice than specifically answering his example. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

First, copy the original table to a new one:

```
CREATE TABLE CopiedTable AS SELECT * FROM OriginalTable;
```

Whenever you want to restore, truncate the original and insert values back into from the copy:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE OriginalTable
INSERT INTO OriginalTable SELECT * FROM CopiedTable
```

Depending on which database you're using, there are faster alternatives.

Also, be careful. As pointed by others, the safest method would be backing up the hole database.

Answer (score 2):

I think the script that I recently used can be useful to somebody.

To backup table you can use next query:

```
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(max), @tableName_bck nvarchar(max)
SET @tableName = 'SomeTable';
SET @tableName_bck = 'SomeTable_bck';


-- Backup
DECLARE @insertCommand nvarchar(max)
--SELECT INTO SomeTable_bck FROM SomeTable
SET @insertCommand = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @tableName_bck + ' FROM ' + @tableName
PRINT @insertCommand
EXEC sp_executesql @insertCommand
```

For restore, because tables often can have IDENTITY fields, you need to SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON and also you need to provide the column list when inserting records. That's why script is a bit more complex:

```
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(max), @tableName_bck nvarchar(max)
SET @tableName = 'SomeTable';
SET @tableName_bck = 'SomeTable_bck';

-- Restore
DECLARE @columnList nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @insertCommand nvarchar(max)

SELECT
    @columnList = SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + column_name AS [text()]
            From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE table_name = @tableName
            ORDER BY table_name
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000);

--INSERT INTO SomeTable(Column1, Column2) SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM SomeTable_bck        
SELECT @insertCommand = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '(' + @columnList + ') SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM ' + @tableName_bck

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT column_name, table_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE table_schema = 'dbo' AND table_name = @tableName
       AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(table_name), column_name, 'IsIdentity') = 1
    )
BEGIN
    SET @insertCommand = 
          'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @tableName + ' ON;' 
        + 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @tableName + ';'
        + @insertCommand + ';'
        + 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @tableName + ' OFF;' 
    /*  
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT SomeTable ON
    TRUNCATE TABLE SomeTable
    INSERT INTO SomeTable(Column1, Column2) SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM SomeTable_bck    
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT SomeTable OFF
    */
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @insertCommand = 
        'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @tableName + ';'
        + @insertCommand
    /*
    TRUNCATE TABLE SomeTable
    INSERT INTO SomeTable(Column1, Column2) SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM SomeTable_bck     
    */
END 

PRINT @insertCommand
EXEC sp_executesql @insertCommand
```

It's easy to see, that you can specify @tableName and @tableName_bck however you like it. For example, this can be in a stored procedure, so the script is reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consdered using a SQL Server unit testing framework such as the open source tSQLt framework?

See http://tsqlt.org/

A tSQLt test runs in a transaction so whatever you do within your test will get rolled back.

It has a concept of a "faketable" which is a copy of the original table minus the constraints, if these get in the way of your test setup.